# Where can questions that are purely about 3D modelling, or CAD, software be asked?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

The [on-topic](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page states that CAD, or 3D software, questions can be asked on SE.3DP, only if they have some *eventual* relevance to 3D printing.

However, if the question is purely about how to draw/design something, without it needing to be printed, where can a user ask these questions, if they are off-topic here? That is to say, where can the user be pointed to? Which Stack Exchange site?

We have had a few of these questions in the past, including:

- [How to horizontally align sketches in fusion360?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/20211/4762)

Answer (score 4):

#### Possible candidates

After asking about, there seems to be two sites that *might* be good candidates<sup>1</sup>:

- Engineering

  - Tag: [CAD](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cad)
  - Tag: [Solidworks](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidworks)
- Graphic Design

  - Tag: [3D](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d)

IMHO, SE.Engineering would seem to be the best location, although it probably depends upon the practical application described by the question. That is to say, if the design is for a logo of a company, then SE.GraphicDesign is probably a better fit.

There is a SE.Computer Graphics (tag: [3D](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d?tab=newest&page=2&pagesize=15)) but that would seem to be more for coding and low-level stuff. I would say that SE.Mathematics is definitely a "no".

#### Blender

Obviously, if the question is about Blender then [SE.Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) is a perfect fit. Blender is a special case as it already has a dedicated SE site. They *also* have a [tag for 3d-printing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-printing).

#### External sites

Another alternative is Reddit, for example

- [reddit.com/r/Fusion360](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fusion360)

However, if and where possible, we really shouldn't be redirecting people away from the "Stack Exchange umbrella".

---

<sup>1</sup> As of yet, I have not had any "buy-in" from the mods or members of those sites. TBH, I haven't even contacted them yet.